# Set a local repo in order apt-get to handle .deb dependecies

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, deb, localrepository

I am trying to do something, which I have already done on `.rpm` distributions, on Fedora more exactly. Basically I want to create a local repository, which I can put a `.deb` file in, so that `apt-get` can handle the package dependecies automatically.

In Fedora this is possible like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13877738/3046584).

Comment: If you're insistant on using apt-get I can't help, though you might also want to look at dpkg as an option for handling deb's. In terms of handling dependancies, once you dpkg -i file.deb, follow it with apt-get install -f and it should fix up the dependancy issues.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you. The solution is not the exact same as it's on `.rpm` but I must admit that this is easier. You can feel free to post it as an answer so that I can upvote it and accept it. In this way someone with the same thought can find the solution faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to accomplish in Debian is different than in Fedora. Save your deb files where ever you like then use `dpkg` to install them.

```
dpkg -i /path/file.deb
```

Once installed

```
apt-get install -f
```

should fix any dependancey issues.

Don't forget to use sudo on these commands if not root.